# How to use stored procedures output in IN clause in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, view

There is a view in  my application which is having an INNER JOIN with another view and a table.

```
view ViewName
select * from AnotherView inner join TableName ON conditions
```

This view is taking too much of time to execute specially with the INNER JOIN statement. So I am trying to improve the performance using SP. I am trying to remove the INNER JOIN on physical table.

My SP will fetch the data required for further clauses.

So the code will look like this,

```
view ViewName
select * from AnotherView where columnName in (result of SP)
```

I tried table variables, calling view within a view. But the execution time seems to be same with some minor differences every time.

Can anyone please help me to understand this ? Can it be possible? Is there any other better way to achieve this. I don't want to make use of openrowset.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: Sounds like you want a table-valued function, not a stored procedure - if you want to make use of the result set.

Comment: What makes you think a stored proc will improve the performance? - if the query is poorly performing as it currently stands, you ought to be examining indexes - not introducing new, opaque code that the optimizer can do *less* with.

Comment: Have you established the cause of the problem? The join might make the query slower but should it be the real concern? What does your `AnotherView` thing look like, for instance?

Comment: AnotherView is just a view which populates data from some other views and physical tables. I made random choice of choosing SP. If I remove the inner join, 1st part of query executes in 2 secs. With inner join it takes 30 secs for almost 40K records.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following query in your view, it will create an inner join with the result of sp.

You can access the sp using OpenRowSet in View.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   AnotherView 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT a.* 
                   FROM   OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
                                     'Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;', 
                                     'EXEC database.dbo.Spname') AS a) AS b 
         ON AnotherView.columnName = b.columnname
```

If the credentials are not in control of developer then You can create a linked server and pass the name of server in openrowset. No need to pass the credentials.

How to create link server to database:

```
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server = N'LinkServerName',
@srvproduct=N'MSSQL',
@provider=N'SQLNCLI',
@provstr=N'PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DbName'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LinkServerName',
@useself=N'True',
@locallogin=NULL
```

How to execute sp in view:

```
SELECT * From OPENQUERY([LinkServerName],DbName.dbo.spname)
```

Comment: I cannot use OPENROWSET. It is a general database which changes as per the client. This setup is not controlled by developer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the result in a temp table and make an inner join with it.

**or**

Put the result in a variable (or output variable) and use Dynamic SQL to use it.

---

To improve performance, use indexes on the columns used in the conditions.

Comment: I have very little knowledge about databases. Can you please guide me in this ?

Comment: You just need to follow one of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+indexes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:pt-PT:official&client=firefox-a